# An invalid preprocessing token

Tags: c++

The following sample is abstracted from my real code, it simulate the error I just encountered:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class CPair
{
public:
    typedef enum {UNKNOW = 0, STRING, YESNO, NUMBER, FLOAT}  TYPE;
};

#define PRT(t)                  \
    printf("%d\n", CPair::##t);

int main()
{
    PRT(NUMBER)
    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling this program on MacOS:

```
$ c++ -v
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

And got the following code:

```
$ c++ t.cpp
t.cpp:14:2: error: pasting formed '::NUMBER', an invalid preprocessing token
        PRT(NUMBER)
        ^
t.cpp:10:24: note: expanded from macro 'PRT'
        printf("%d\n", CPair::##t);
                              ^
1 error generated.
```

This code is copied from my old code that was working with Linux g++ compiler. What's the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The result of concatenation must be a single preprocessing token. And such a token cannot contain `::`, it has to be a valid identifier.

The immediate fix is simple, since you don't need token pasting at all:

```
#define PRT(t)                  \
    printf("%d\n", CPair::t);
```

Comment: To be explicit: the `##` should never have been there in the first place, and would not be required by any conforming compiler.

Comment: @TieDad So you're primarily trying to waste everyone's time here before you try something yourself?